# c++: accessing the member of a parent class

Tags: c++, templates

I have this base and these derived classes

```
class AlarmType
{
    public:
        unsigned int alarmIndex;
};

class TrendAlarmType : public AlarmType
{
    public:
        typedef enum 
        {
            decreasing = 0, //will be used as index apart from enum
            steady,
            increasing
        } Trend_types;

        Trend_types alarmIndex2;
};

class ThresholdAlarmType : public AlarmType
{
    public:
        typedef enum 
        { 
            low = 0, //will be used as index apart from enum
            lowmid,
            highmid,
            high,
        } Threshold_types;

        Threshold_types alarmIndex3;
};
```

Here `alarmIndex2` and `alarmIndex3` are of different type so `AlarmType::alarmIndex` should not exist.
Is it possible to declare template
Ideally, `alarmIndex` would be a template member of the base class and `alarmIndex2 & 3` would not exist. Is it possible? I am trying to implement `AlarmType` as a template class

```
template< typename T>
class AlarmType
{
    public:
        unsigned int alarmIndex;
};
```

and then try to access `alarmIndex` from the derived classes as follows

```
alarmIndex<Trend_types> = tt;  OR
alarmIndex<Threshold_types> = tt;
```

I get a large number of errors starting with a "error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token" on line

```
class TrendAlarmType : public AlarmType
{ ...
```

if I try to add the type I want

```
class TrendAlarmType : public AlarmType<Trend_types>
{ ...
```

The `Trend_types` have not been declared yet. So I get into other troubles. Is there a way to declare the variable in the base class?

Thank you

Comment: Well, your main error is that you forgot to terminate your class declarations with a semi-colon.  Do that first, then see what errors remain.

Comment: It was never an error on the code. I just did not copy everything from my files here. Fixed the entries here though to avoid confusion.

Comment: I feel like there's something... strange about the way you're managing the problem. For inheritance, it doesn't seem like you can remove parts of an inherited class and substitute it without doing a top-level substitution on the base class' alarm index type. The ideal way would be to provide the enum type when you instantiate the class and then have the enums around somewhere in your namespace, header, or somewhere accessible to the parts of code.

Comment: Even if you got it to compile, it wouldn't help you. The template parameter is part of the type, so your two derived types would have *different* parent types.

Comment: It's preferable to use `enum X { .... };` instead of `typedef enum { .... } X;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish, but I believe what you're looking for is not inheritance but template aliasing, which was introduced in C++11 (a C++11-supporting compiler is required):

```
typedef enum
        {
        decreasing = 0, //will be used as index apart from enum
        steady,
        increasing
        } Trend_types;

typedef enum
        {
        low = 0, //will be used as index apart from enum
        lowmid,
        highmid,
        high,
        } Threshold_types;    

template<typename T> using alarmIndex=T;
```

This makes it possible to use the following syntax:

```
alarmIndex<Trend_types> t1 = decreasing;
alarmIndex<Threshold_types> t2 = lowmid;
```

This seems to be the syntax that you are trying to achieve, according to your question.

But let's go a step further, and enforce type-safety using enum classes:

```
enum class Trend_types
{
    decreasing = 0, //will be used as index apart from enum
    steady,
    increasing
};

enum class Threshold_types
{
    low = 0, //will be used as index apart from enum
    lowmid,
    highmid,
    high,
};

template<typename T> using alarmIndex=T;

// ...

alarmIndex<Trend_types> t1 = Trend_types::decreasing;
alarmIndex<Threshold_types> t2 = Threshold_types::lowmid;
```

With an enum class, the compiler will enforce type-safety, and will reject an attempt to assign a `Threshold_types` value to a `Trend_types` instance (try it yourself).

Note that the template alias is generic, and will provide this syntactic sugar with any class, not just these two.

It's possible, with a little more work, to restrict the template alias to work only with these two classes, if you really want to.